# I've got a problem in case 2 of the switch that gives me the NoSuchElementException?

Tags: java, macos, exception, netbeans

I have the following code that works correctly at the school in a Windows computer, but it doesn't work in my MacOS. Case 2 should give a student's class number but it is giving me the `NoSuchElementException` only in my MacOS. Why it doesn't work in my MacOS?

```
case 2:
            System.out.println("Inserisci il cognome dello studente");
            String surname = scan.next();
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Inserisci il nome dello studente");
            String name = scan.next();
            System.out.println("");

            File directory = new File("files" + File.separator + "class");;
            int fileCount = directory.list().length;
            for(int i=0; i< fileCount; i++ ){
                cn = ClassNumber.values()[enumNumb];
                if(enumNumb<3){
                    for(int j = 1; j<6; j++){
                        File serchStudents = new File("files" + File.separator + "class//" + j + cn + ".txt");
                        Scanner scS = new Scanner(serchStudents);
                        while(scS.hasNextLine()){
                            if(surname.equals(scS.next())/*&& name.equals(sc.next())*/){
                                System.out.print(j);
                                System.out.println(cn);
                                enumNumb=0;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    enumNumb++;
                }
                if(enumNumb>=3){
                    for(int j = 3; j<6; j++){
                        File serchStudents = new File("files" + File.separator + "class" + File.separator + j + cn + ".txt");
                        Scanner scS = new Scanner(serchStudents);
                        while(scS.hasNextLine()){
                            if(surname.equals(scS.next())/*&& name.equals(sc.next())*/){
                                System.out.println("Lo studente fa parte della classe : ");
                                System.out.print(j);
                                System.out.println(cn);
                                i=fileCount;
                                enumNumb=0;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    enumNumb++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Vuoi fare altro ?");
            answer = scan.next();
            break;
```

Comment: Can you please share the console output for the exception? Any idea which line this error occurred?

Comment: i don't know how but i think i just solved the problem :-o  , anyway thank you and sorry for waisting your time. I just installed something on netBeans that has needed to be installed i guess.

Comment: Good job! Please close this question by answering it and selecting your answer as the right answer. :)

Comment: It would be good if you could change your question title to something more appropriate. Try to think on something that would easily pop up in a search.

Answer (score 0):

I've just installed something on netBeans that has needed to be installed and it has worked so its fine i guess.

Comment: Could you be more specific so you might help others in the future? What have you installed?

Comment: i'don't rememberer what it was but netbeans notified me so guess it would do the same with other users